# Apply rights to folders every night via a CSV file where rights are located

Tags: powershell, file, ntfs

I am developing a PowerShell script to read the rights of 2-level folders from the root and re-apply them each night.

I managed to extract the rights in a CSV but to re-apply them I find a great difficulty. Can somebody help me, please, to develop this code?

This is the first part done :

```
$FolderPath = "C:\Users\klengliz\Documents\"
$extractPathDad = "C:\Users\klengliz\Documents\FolderPermissions.csv"
$FoldersToScan = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory 
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FoldersToScan) {
#Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Directory| ForEach-Object {

 $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName

    foreach ($Access in $acl.SDDL)
        {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'SDDL'=$Access}
            $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
  #  }
}
$Report | Export-CSV $extractPathDad -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code so that we can see what you are doing. There are many ways that you can save the rights information; not all of them are equally useful, and how you save them may have an effect on how you need to apply them.

Comment: This is literally what [`secedit /configure` is for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit-configure)

Comment: This is very much like what I needed to do for a system fix where we have a requirement to be able to roll back the fix. Instead of storing the rights information in a "human readable" form, we used the SDDL description of the ACL, and if we need to roll back the fix, we don't have to rebuild it, just apply the SDDL.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: Consider your statement in the script above `$ACL = Get-ACL -Path $Folder.FullName`. If you look at `$ACL.Access`, you get a "human-readable" description of the ACL, showing the rights for each entity. The SDDL, which may be accessed by `$ACL.SDDL`, "encodes" this into a string that is not readable without interpretation, but which can be used with the `SetSecurityDescriptorSDDLForm()` method to apply _all_ of the rights that you see enumerated in `$ACL.Access` in one operation.

Comment: Thus, if instead of trying to parse `$ACL.Access` and saving that in the CSV, simply save `$ACL.SDDL` in your CSV. Then, when you need to reapply it, read it in from the CSV, read the existing ACL, apply the ACL from the CSV using `$ACL = $ACL.SetSecurityDescriptorSDDLForm(...)`, and write the updated ACL back to the folder with `Set-ACL`.